# how does calldata not work in this case?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

contract D {
    
    function test2(uint[1] calldata good) external {
        
        uint c = good[0];
    }
    
    
}
```

This code is perfectly valid. What I do is deploy it, then call `test2` function from `remix` and pass `[99]` , then get the transaction hash and try to debug it. as soon as I click `start debugging`, Debugger just disappears completely.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: It looks like a Remix bug. If you haven't reported it yet I urge to do so at their github's repo https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project.

Comment: Will do right away. By the way, have you taken a look at my latest question ?

Comment: I read your last question but I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thank you still, while you're here - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92693/how-does-gas-get-taken-from-the-account can you take a look at this ?